# Finding sum of all integer substring using dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was solving [Sam and substrings problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sam-and-substrings/problem) from hackerrank. It is basically finding sum of all substrings of a string having all integers.

> Samantha and Sam are playing a numbers game. Given a number as a string, no leading zeros, determine the sum of all integer values of substrings of the string.

> Given an integer as a string, sum all of its substrings cast as integers. As the number may become large, return the value modulo 10⁹ + 7.

> Example: `n = '42'`

> Here *n* is a string that has three integer substrings: 4, 2, and 42. Their sum is 48, and 48 modulo 10⁹ + 7 = 48.

## Function Description

> Complete the substrings function in the editor below.
> substrings has the following parameter(s):
> string n: the string representation of an integer
> Returns

int: the sum of the integer values of all substrings in *n*, modulo (10⁹ + 7)

I tried following recursive top down dynamic problem solution with memoization:

```
from functools import cache

def substrings(n):
    @cache
    def substrSum(curIndex):
        if curIndex == 0: return int(n[0])
        return substrSum(curIndex-1)*10 + int(n[curIndex]) * (curIndex+1)
        
    totalSum = 0
    for i in range(len(n)-1, -1,-1): 
        totalSum += substrSum(i) 
        
    return totalSum % (10 ** 9 + 7)
```

I also tried recursive bottom up dynamic programming solution with memoization (this simply involves changing `for` loop counting direction):

```
from functools import cache

def substrings(n):
    @cache
    def substrSum(curIndex):
        if curIndex == 0: return int(n[0])
        return substrSum(curIndex-1)*10 + int(n[curIndex]) * (curIndex+1)
        
    totalSum = 0
    for i in range(len(n)): 
        totalSum += substrSum(i) 
        
    return totalSum % (10 ** 9 + 7)
```

For top-down solution gives runtime error in 8 out of 13 test cases, whearas in bottom up solution gives gives runtime error in 6 out of 13 test cases. Where am I making mistake?

Comment: Only skimming your code, it appears you might only be looking at substrings that remove the first n characters, not all substrings. Standard debugging tip: add print statements to make sure your code is doing what you think it's doing

Comment: For those of us without HackerRank accounts, can you provide a *bit* more detail about what the problem is asking for?

Comment: @BarryCarter yeah I usually do that. But the problem with hackerrank is that it does not show inputs of failed test cases. Those are hidden. So we have to keep generating custom test cases, guess what SHOULD be the output for them (by pen and paper, as hackerrank does not even show what is expected output for custom test cases) and then check if the code is giving that output. I used to quickly generate several custom test case using random generator but we still have to calculate expected output by pen and paper. Is there any trick to deal with this difficulty of checking custom test cases?

Comment: The problem is not just generating random number. Even if generate tens of random test cases, we dont know what should be the answer for them. We have to solve them manually and then check if our code gives the output. For simpler problems this might take less time but for complex ones, I feel this approach is not suitable, right?

Comment: But Leetcode reveals the failed test cases and also tells the expected output for custom test cases.

Comment: @ruakh [here](https://i.postimg.cc/9MtRZKrm/image.png) is the screenshot of the whole hackerrank problem

Comment: @Rnj: Thanks! So, just to clarify what you're looking for with this Stack Overflow question . . . I don't think dynamic programming is the best approach for this HackerRank problem, because the problem can be solved in a single pass without extra storage. Are you open to other solutions, or are you specifically looking to understand the problem with the solution you've posted?

Comment: You can generate small test cases and solve them with brute-force approach O(n^2), so n = 100 should still work, then compare with your implementation.

Comment: @maraca: *Pure* brute force here is at least O(n^3), and probably more than that if it relies on Python's big-integer support to parse a hundred-digit string and do math on it. So n = 100 might be excessive, but n = 20 or so would certainly be reasonable.

Comment: Well yes if I understand it correctly there are anyway only 6 digits max in the string, seems to be ridiculously small, so brute force would solve the problem easily. Anyway O(n^2) is not that hard to get. Even O(nlogn) is possible.

Comment: Constraints are wrong on hackerrank it seems, it is not n cast as integer <= 2*10^5, it is the max length of the string. O(n) is possible too.

Comment: `return totalSum % (10 ** 9 + 7)` That's a rather Neanderthal approach. If your total sum has a million digits, what are the chances your intermediate results also have about the same number of digits? Why waste time summing up a million million-digit numbers?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Note that the problem spec is incorrect about the input size. With the spec as given, it might very well be **faster** to do one final modulo instead of one for each digit.

Comment: @KellyBundy With the spec as given, the final answer will be far smaller than the ridiculous constant anyway. But we now know that the spec is wrong.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I tried quickly doing `% MOD` for every sum in `return` statement. But it started giving WRONG ANSWER error. But didnt give more time fixing the same. Probably I did it wrong way. What you suggest?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the exact code

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm is correct (both versions), but HackerRank will test with strings that have many thousands of digits, and as you perform a recursive call for each digit, your first code runs into a *maximum recursion depth exceeded* error, and the second one runs into a memory error (think of the cache).

It should be noted that they phrased the *constraint* wrong. It is not the value of *n* "cast to integer" that is limited by 2 x 10<sup>5</sup>, but the **number of digits** in *n*. I checked this, and one of their tests concerns a string of about 199000 digits.

Comment: How do you know what their test cases are if they are secret?

Comment: I "paid" for unlocking one.

Comment: Aah!! Super thanks to confirm!! Now am feeling that we should stick to iterative approaches wherever possible...its just that recursive code with `@cache` looks way too minimal and elegant, so I am almost always tempted to do it this way!!