# No solution works for Longest Common Subsequence problem

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was going through [common child problem on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/common-child/problem). It is nothing but [a Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem.

Tried it solving as follows:

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    LCS_table = [[0 for _ in range(len(s2)+1)] 
                 for _ in range(len(s1)+1)
                ]              
    for i in range(1,len(s1)+1):
        for j in range(1,len(s2)+1):            
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]: #Mistake not [i] & [j] but [i-1] & [j-1] Ref: $A1
                LCS_table[i][j] = LCS_table[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                LCS_table[i][j] = max(LCS_table[i-1][j], LCS_table[i][j-1])
    return LCS_table[-1][-1]
```

Eight test cases passed, but six test cases gave "Time Limit Exceeded" error. I quickly googled online solutions and tried them. But for all of them was able to pass more than half of the test cases, but failing at other with time limit exceeded error:

**Sol 2** [ref](https://hackerranksolution.in/commonchildinterviewprep/)

```
def commonChild(a, b):
    m = len(a)
    n = len(b)
    prev = [0 for x in range(n + 1)]
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        curr = [0 for x in range(n + 1)]
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            curr[j] = max(prev[j], curr[j - 1])
            if a[i - 1] == b[j - 1]:
                curr[j] = max(curr[j], prev[j - 1] + 1)
        prev = curr
    return curr[n]
```

**Sol 3** [ref](https://www.thepoorcoder.com/hackerrank-common-child-solution/)

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    m = [[0]*(len(s2)+1) for _ in range(len(s1)+1)]
    for i,c in enumerate(s1,1):
        for j,d in enumerate(s2,1):
            if c == d:
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j-1]+1
            else:
                m[i][j] = max(m[i][j-1],m[i-1][j])
                   
    return m[-1][-1]
```

Are we all missing some idea to make it execute even faster?

Comment: I can't access hackerrank, so I don't know what the specific problem is.  Are you sure there is no simpler solution than longest common subsequence?  hackerrank seems to be telling you that there is a better solution than O(mn).

Comment: @FrankYellin Nah I think hackerrank is telling them that there is a better Python than CPython. (Better at this.) I'd try it but I'm on a phone and their editor is entirely broken.

Comment: @FrankYellin Here is the [screenshot of hackerrank problem description](https://i.postimg.cc/FHyHWvRQ/image.png). And yes, thats exactly what I want to know, if there is any better approach than dynamic programming idea implemented by all above solutions.

Comment: One of the test cases (failed 2 out of 14!) has the string of ```5000```~ $#%  I prob. will have to switch to C code ... ;-)

Comment: @DanielHao What language did you select?

Comment: @DanielHao And do you fail with Pypy 3 as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that gets accepted with Python 3, i.e., doesn't need PyPy:

```
def commonChild(s1, s2):
    L = [0] * len(s2)
    for c in s1:
        p = 0
        L = [
            p := (q+1 if c==d else r if p < r else p)
            for d, q, r in zip(s2, [0]+L, L)
        ]
    return L[-1]
```

It's about five times faster than your solutions in my own testing.

Main tricks are to avoid `max()`, avoid reading by index (zipping instead) and avoid writing by index (use list comp instead).

My `L` is the latest row of the `LCS_table`, and my variables `p`, `q` and `r` mean `LCS_table[i][j-1]`, `LCS_table[i-1][j-1]` and `LCS_table[i-1][j]`.

Thanks to @Daniel for testing this at HackerRank (I can't, their editor is utterly unusable for me on my phone).

---

For some more clarity, it's:

[image]
(where "p+1" means "next p-value", the one computed in the `...` of `p := (...)` and then assigned to `p`)

To help you visualize what how above zipping works:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> s2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> zip(s2,[0]+L,L)
[('a', 0, 1), ('b', 1, 2), ('c', 2, 3), ('d', 3, 4), ('e', 4, 5), ('f', 5, 6)]
```

Also whats [`:=` in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291997/how-can-i-do-assignments-in-a-list-comprehension)?

Comment: (sorry for being late to reply) This is super clever! But, now am wondering if this is the only way to make it work in CPython? Or is there another algorithmic optimisation or completely different algorithm to solve it. Also, if I recall it correct, I also tried to copy paste run C solution on some websites and they failed too at some test cases. So was guessing if indeed there is some other way to solve this.

Comment: @Rnj [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) has some alternatives/improvements, and some optimizations could happen to be better for their particular test cases. Top-down with memorization might get lucky and not need most of the matrix, or before the algorithm you could filter out characters that don't appear on both strings. The latter is something I saw in someone's accepted solution afterwards. You could look through those accepted CPython solutions as well. All that said, I think this is the "standard" algorithm and intended to be used there.

Comment: "You could look through those accepted CPython solutions as well." - can you please tell where to find these accepted solutions? I just checked the [discussion thread of the same problem on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/common-child/forum) and I couldnt find any cpython solution there. All python solutions there say they get some issues (including time limit exceeded)

Comment: @Rnj In the [leaderboard](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/common-child/leaderboard).

Answer (score 2):

@Rnj - if you switch to PyPy3 - all three versions will pass with flying color.  So your logic is all sound, but the CPython just too slow in this particular case unfortunately.

I've tried many times earlier with diff. approaches - until @Kelly reminded me the *faster* version is also available there.  *Lesson learned.*

Big kudos to @Kelly.

Comment: The more interesting challenge of course is to get accepted with CPython :-). Might be hard. I measured their first solution elsewhere with `s1 = 'a' * 5000` and 
`s2 = 'b' * 5000` and PyPy took about 1 second while CPython took about 16 seconds.

Comment: Althou [this](https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500002392722--Execution-Environment-and-Samples) says CPython has a higher limit (10 seconds vs 4). Might be doable with the same basic algorithm and just some micro-optimizations.

Comment: It's very hard to ace with Cpython - given some unreasonable string data. Love to see one.
.

Comment: Could you try submitting [this](https://tio.run/##VU7LDoIwELz7FXMsggnFiyFy8to/IBwMLYGktEuBg/48ttVA3NM8dnaHXktvzfVGbtuk6tDacbTm0Q9asplnmIukPMHPXKDCspJWbHwSs05GM4mm8F6dNzhDK8O8HNXOOrQYDI4A/10LQz6U7yye2NnXLyuwKeUYfK@qklB6VnCBEu4eRE7JXyo89Z@mLCwavAfyfbLQLhUZxLHcROTUsjoDUV94s20f)? (Their retarded editor just doesn't let me type/paste code). Seems about 5 times faster than OP's first code.

Comment: And also a [less optimized](https://tio.run/##VU7BDoMgFLvvK3rUyRLZLosZp135A8NJMJIoILjD9vMMMHFZT21fmz733iZrbnfnY5RqxGCXxZrnpGdZBUoQrnV3QgIHQ98KnDErUyW7uKP1GKANAt1jGS5F20OV4qH2e8dQrQ2FToOMSag5KPgsHR6JFO3qv1aekgQryUGDj3bpC5J/ajgB/4VFYV5tL2/A@wsVMX4B) version that's only slightly slower.

Comment: @KellyBundy *Congrats* - both version you posted passing in ```Python 3```!  Is there some tricks...;-)   I think you should post the answers with some analysis.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Posted now with a little explanation.

Comment: (sorry for being late to reply) I always saw PyPy in hackerrank, but never cared to find whats that! Now this is holy grail!! Am wondering what kinds of solutions will it execute that CPython fails at? Will it also run recursive dynamic programming implementations which fails with CPython due "maximum recursion depth exceeded error" something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347777/13782227) especially because it has something called [stackless feature](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stackless.html) (though I dont know what it is)?