# Comparing various python implementations of solution to longest common subsequence puzzle

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was going through [common child problem on hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/common-child/problem). It is exactly same as [a famous Longest Common Subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem.

Using [basic concept from CLRS](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap15/15.4/), I implemented first solution. But  exceeds time limit on some test cases:

```
def lcs1(s1, s2):
    LCS_table = [[0 for _ in range(len(s2)+1)] # s2 corresponds to columns
                 for _ in range(len(s1)+1) # s1 corresponds to rows
                ]              
    for i in range(1,len(s1)+1): 
        for j in range(1,len(s2)+1): 
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]: 
                LCS_table[i][j] = LCS_table[i-1][j-1] + 1
            else:
                LCS_table[i][j] = LCS_table[i-1][j] if LCS_table[i-1][j] > LCS_table[i][j-1] else LCS_table[i][j-1]
    return LCS_table[-1][-1]
```

So I went through the leaderboard of hackerrank and come up with second solution which passes all testcases:

```
def lcs2(s1,s2):
    prev = cur = [0] * (len(s2)+1) 
    for i in range(1, len(s1)+1):
        for j in range(1, len(s2)+1):
            if s1[i-1] == s2[j-1]:
                cur[j] = prev[j-1]+1
            else:
                cur[j] = prev[j] if prev[j] > cur[j-1] else cur[j-1]
        prev, cur = cur, [0] * (len(s2)+1)
    return prev[-1]
```

**Q1.** Is it because indexing 2D array in `lcs1` is costlier than indexing 1D array in `lcs2`?

I also referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588477/13782227) solution:

```
def lcs3(s1, s2):
    L = [0] * len(s2)
    for c in s1:
        p = 0
        L = [
            p := (q+1 if c==d else r if p < r else p)
            for d, q, r in zip(s2, [0]+L, L)
        ]
    return L[-1]
```

I chosen two random strings and tried these methods on them:

```
s1='onfjkvbibisbwbriuiwbviwovwwwwmpomqqsbambviubivbsvbwb'
s2='ieubrvbwoqpvponvnxvknoibolkncnsnbvrobrobwvkskdvksvorbqppqwqwqzcx'
print(lcs1(s1,s2)) # 18
print(lcs2(s1,s2)) # 19
print(lcs3(s1,s2)) # 18
```

**Q2.** Surprisingly the output of `lcs2` differs from that of `lcs1` and `lcs3`. Where did I make mistake in lcs2? Still how it got accepted in hackerrank? Lack of good test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lcs2` version tries to be more memory efficient than `lcs1` is. The `lcs1` version has a 2D matrix, but we can see that in one iteration of the outer loop, only 2 rows in the table are actually used: the row with index `i-1` serves for updating row with index `i`. That means that for a given value if `i`, the rows with indices less than `i-1` are no longer used in the rest of algorithm. That is space that could have been freed. Only two rows matter during the whole process.

And that is what `lcs2` tried to do. It gives the row with index `i-1` the name `prev`, and the row with index `i` it names `curr`. Then in the next iteration, `prev` will be what `curr` was in the previous iteration, and `curr` gets a new list to work with which is only allocated when it is now needed. The previous list that `prev` referenced is then no longer accessible and can be garbage collected.

So far the good intentions of `lcs2`. But as you found out, it has a problem. Maybe someone broke the original code of `lcs2`, thinking it could be simplified a bit. Here is the issue:

```
    prev = cur = [0] * (len(s2)+1)
```

This creates **one** list, not two. And both `prev` and `curr` reference it. That is a problem, because in the first iteration every mutation of the `curr` list, will be a mutation in the `prev` list, because they are the *same* list! This is not what is supposed to happen.

If you change this piece of initialisation to this:

```
    prev = [0] * (len(s2)+1) 
    cur = [0] * (len(s2)+1)
```

...it will work fine, and return the same results as `lcs1` and `lcs3`.

Comment: Sorry to revisit this answer late. Thanks to point out the mistake with `rev = cur = [0] * (len(s2)+1)`.  So Q2 got answered. But I guess Q1 remains unanswered? You explained how lcs2 improves space complexity over lcs1, but did not explained how lcs2 improves time complexity of lcs1? My guession was indexing 2D array in `lcs1` is costlier than indexing 1D array in `lcs2`. Is that why `lcs2` gets accepted by hackerrank but `lcs1` does not?

Comment: Double indexing like with `LCS_table[i][j]` takes more time than `cur[j]`. Although this does not change the time complexity, it is expected that the first kind of access will need a factor more time than the second.